# Fetch values from multiple json array urls

Tags: php, arrays, loops, curl, foreach

I need to get the **[result]->[data]->[id]->xx** informations out of extern item-API json arrays. I want to save them in a mysql table (items).

**Example url to the first json array:**

[https://eu.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/search/item?namespace=static-eu&orderby=id&_pageSize=1000&id=[1,]&_page=1&locale=de_DE&access_token=USPqoKWmdURvO1mmDeW5vRghI5dojO13XZ](https://eu.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/search/item?namespace=static-eu&orderby=id&_pageSize=1000&id=%5B1,%5D&_page=1&locale=de_DE&access_token=USPqoKWmdURvO1mmDeW5vRghI5dojO13XZ)

You see the **[1,]** in the url. This is the **minimum item ID** from wehere I want to start fetching.

The maximum items one json array url can show is 1000. The API has over 170.000 items for which I need their particular [data] [id]. The API calls are limited to 100 per second and 36.000 per hour.

**My idea** is to get the **last** [data] [id] value from the current array. Then in the next loop I add 1 to the last arrays´ [data] [id] value as the starting point for the next loop. And so on.

**In the example url the last item id is 2429. So in the next loop 2430 would be the starting point.**

[https://eu.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/search/item?namespace=static-eu&orderby=id&_pageSize=1000&id=[2430,]&_page=1&locale=de_DE&access_token=USPqoKWmdURvO1mmDeW5vRghI5dojO13XZ](https://eu.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/search/item?namespace=static-eu&orderby=id&_pageSize=1000&id=%5B2430,%5D&_page=1&locale=de_DE&access_token=USPqoKWmdURvO1mmDeW5vRghI5dojO13XZ)

This is my code. I don´t know how to loop this and if this would be possible to do. Maybe there is an easier solutiuon.

```
 //**Decode JSON in PHP ARRAY**//

function getSslPage($url, $userAgent)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($result, true);
}

$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0';

//**GET the [DATA] [ID] value of the last KEY in the CURRENT array**//

$all_values = array_values($data['results']);
$last_value = end($all_values);

//**In the next LOOP the [DATA] [ID] VALUE should be +1 as the new starting point**//

$startingItem = $last_value['data']['id'] + 1;

$url = "https://eu.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/search/item?namespace=static-eu&orderby=id&_pageSize=1000&id=[$startingItem,]&_page=1&locale=de_DE&access_token=USPqoKWmdURvO1mmDeW5vRghI5dojO13XZ";

$data = getSslPage($url, $userAgent);

//** INSERT in database **//

foreach ($data['results'] as $entry) {

       $sqle= "REPLACE INTO `items`
                (`id`)
            VALUES
                ('{$entry['data']['id']}')";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PHP version > 7.3 you can retrieve the last index key using [array_key_last()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-last.php)

By the way you are retrieving your last key using

`end($all_values)`.

Watch out for the comma (,) at the end of that index, you should [trim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) your index string to contain only numbers, try with

`$newkey = trim($key, ',')`

Then you can retrieve its int value with [intval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

`$intnewkey = intval($newkey)`.

Now you will be able to increment your index with

`$intnewkey++;`,

return back to string with [strval()](https://www.php.net/strval)

`$newIndex = strval($intnewkey)`

and then append again the comma to your new value for you API Call:

`$newIndexForAPI = $newIndex . ','`